# How to redirect to same page in struts

Tags: java, redirect, struts

I am fresher in struts.
I have written code for `login.jsp` and `profile.jsp` both are contained in same directory.
When I successfully login is showing profile.jap page but when fail its not redirecting to same page means `login.jsp`.

generally login page path is

> http://localhost:8000/brand/jsppages/login.jsp

but when I fail its redirecting to

> http://localhost:8000/brand/login.do

my struts-config.xml is

```
<action  input="/login.jsp" name="LoginForm" path="/login" scope="session" type="brandzter.strutsaction.LoginAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/jsppages/profile.jsp" />
        <forward name="failure" path="/jsppages/login.jsp" />
    </action>
```

I am not following why its redirecting to login.do page whenever I have given "/jsppages/login.jsp" path for failure.

here is the Action class-

```
public class LoginAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    private final static String SUCCESS = "success";
    private final static String FAILURE = "failure";

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
        boolean availableStatus = CustomerManager.matchUserIdPassword(loginForm.getLoginid(), loginForm.getPassword());
        if (availableStatus) {
            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
        } else {
            return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

I did debug this is going to login.jsp page but not showing given url.

Comment: The redirection is normally controlled by forwards returned by your action class. How does `brandzter.strutsaction.LoginAction` look ? Post its code. Most likely the problem is in it

Comment: I would like to see the web.xml configuration to direct to struts filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean availableStatus = CustomerManager.matchUserIdPassword(loginForm.getLoginid(), loginForm.getPassword());
```

I think your mistake is in this. it will not allowed you to get directly value by calling.
    loginform.getLoginid();
You have to called it like this

```
boolean availableStatus = CustomerManager.matchUserIdPassword(loginForm.getString("PropertyNameofTextBox"), loginForm.getString("PropertyNameofTextBox"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear unless to post some code from you action. But most likely you are doing a validation (in `LoginForm` ) which is failing. As a result of which the flow is getting redirected to configured `input` parameter of `action` which is configured from root (`/login.jsp`). Try changing that `/jsppages/login.jsp`.

Comment: validation form not failing after validate its redirecting to wrong page.